# Is there a way to configure Gatling from within a Simulation?

Tags: gatling

Is there a way to configure Gatling from within a Simulation? I try to set lowerBound and higherBound from within Scala. I figured out how to overwrite it:

```
val props = new HashMap[String, Any]()
props += ("gatling.charting.indicators.lowerBound" -> 5)
props += ("gatling.charting.indicators.higherBound" -> 100)
GatlingConfiguration.setUp(props)
```

But I just want to add two properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's too late: the configuration is loaded prior to the simulation.